# iOS Website. Make telephone number not Clickable

Tags: iphone, ios, web, click, tel

If you want to make a telephone number Clickable you could do this with "tel:" But what the other way around? Whats if there is a Callerid and i want that this Callerid is not Clickable?

Answer (score 5):

You should add the following code in your html page to prevent a hyperlink around phone numbers:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```